# Java giving out of bounds exception when calling function twice?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm trying to find out if there is a variable that exists at some point in an `ArrayList`, but, when calling the function that does this, twice, I get an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But when the function is called only once, it doesn't give an error, even though, when calling the function twice, they check to see if different indexes exist, not the same one.

Code;

```
//package mj.mjo.Vars;
public boolean varExists(int index){
    return mjo_vars.get(index) != null;
}
```

Note, mjo here is a variable, with vars being another variable that is the mj.mjo.Vars class

```
//package mj.play.StudioCanvas;
int nonsys = mjo.vars.setVar("TEST", "LOLOLOL", false); // returns 1
int yessys = mjo.vars.setVar("SYSVARTEST", "WOOHO!", true); // returns 2

System.out.println("DOES THE VAR \"TEST\" EXIST? " + mjo.vars.varExists(nonsys));
System.out.println("DOES THE VAR \"TEST\" EXIST? " + mjo.vars.varExists(yessys));
```

Comment: Are you by any chance adding to the ArrayList and returning the *count* instead of actual position? I'd wager that `setVar()` *should* be returning `0` and `1` instead.

Comment: Why is it, I bet you are correct? Lol, I'll check now.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Though I will also mark dasblinkenlight's answer as correct, since it is also constructive, and you haven't made an answer. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the value of `index` that you pass to `get()` is greater than or is equal to the number of elements in the list. Change your code as follows to avoid the exception:

```
public boolean varExists(int index){
    return index >= 0
        && index < mjo_vars.size()
        && mjo_vars.get(index) != null;
}
```

In general, the error means that something is wrong with your indexing scheme: list and array indexes in Java start at zero, and end at `size()-1`, inclusive. If passing `2` triggers the exception, but passing `1` is OK, then the list has only two elements - at indexes `0` and `1`.

Comment: Completely makes sense, and sorts the error from happening again. I was just being ignorant, thanks for posting this. Very helpful.